# Python SQLite3 - Is there a way to search for a table based on user input without injection risk?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a website where a user can select from multiple tables to browse data, but I am having trouble accomplishing this in a way that doesn't expose my website to injection since you cannot do parameterized searches for tables, columns ect.

What I want to do is this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ?", (selected_table,))
```

which returns an error and forces me to do this to make it work:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM {0} ".format(selected_table))
```

which exposes my server to injection. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why are you using raw queries with django to begin with?

Comment: you can always create list/set of allowed tables and check if `selected_table` is in this list/set.

Comment: Building on Furas' suggestion, keep a mapping of display names to SQL identifiers.  Show the display names to users so that you aren't exposing your database's internals.

Comment: [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#the-filter) is made for this and allows you to define what operations are allowed and what to name them. The real question is indeed why you are not using the Django ORM.